# Security of PS Remoting in production servers

Tags: c#, security, powershell, powershell-remoting, windows-server-2012-r2

I created a small web application in C# to run the PowerShell scripts remotely. I am using below configurations to call the PowerShell scripts.

```cs
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, server, 5985, "/wsman", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", new PSCredential(userName, password));
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
connectionInfo.ProxyAuthentication = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate;
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
{                
}
```

I have to enable PowerShell remoting in the remote machine to use that tool. This is fine in testing and pre-prod environment, but for the production environment it is a question about security. It is an online trading site with more than 500 customer-facing servers. All servers are in an AD domain. So I want know the possibilities of security threat against hackers/surface attackers and how secure enabling PowerShell remote in production server is.

I read below blogs which is telling it is security thread to enable PS remoting.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/20/windows-powershell-and-the-windows-management-framework.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/02/18/hey-scripting-guy-february-18-2010a.aspx

But the above blogs are for PowerShell 2.0 and I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 with PowerShell 4.0. I am not sure how security things got changed. I have to convince my manager and Solution architect that there is no security threat with enabling PowerShell remoting in prod server to use this tool for deployment.

Could you please anyone share your thoughts on this?

And also please suggest me is there any other possibilities to execute the PowerShell script remotely with secured from C#.

Comment: This question should probably be asked on [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/). From my point of view *every* additional service *does* have a security impact. The question is against which threats you want to protect it.

Comment: The question should not be "is it secure?".  The question should be "How secure can we make it?".  There are a number of things you can do in the configuration of those sessions to enhance security, and additional security features are available in WMF 5, but you have to implement them.

Comment: @Both Thanks for your inputs. I am new to security things. Sorry for any stupid questions.  All I want know is whether PowerShell Remoting will create any new opportunities for hackers or not. If not I am happy to proceed further.

Comment: There is no simple Yes/No answer to your question.  If you've been paying attention it should be apparent that for the foreseeable future, Powershell will be the management platform for Windows servers and remoting will be a part of that strategy. If your organization hasn't got a handle on Powershell security yet then they probably need to find a consultant to answer these questions. If you are "new to security things" then you probably shouldn't be trying to answer those questions for them, and they shouldn't be asking you to.

Comment: One other thing: I'm no security "expert", but leading practice that I've seen / followed is that you should always assume that enabling a service (including WMF) will increase the threat surface on a target, just like adding a window to a building increases the number of entry points. With that said, I would also agreed with the comment from @mjolinor that you should have a consultant come in to help evaluate these things if you would like to consider them as an organization.

Comment: @mjolinor, Thanks for your suggestions. Sure I will check the possibilities that you suggested.

Comment: @PSGuy - Enabling PS remoting does add another "entry point" and increase the attack surface if you're doing it in addition to traditional remote management methods like RDP.  You can effect a substantial net reduction in the attack surface if you enable and properly configure PS remoting and then remove the GUI and all the components required to support it. The decisions to make Server Core the default install and enable PS remoting by default were not arbitrary. There is a method to that madness.

Comment: @mjolinor, I completely agree about proper configuration of PS Remoting. If everything is properly configured, then there's *no* reason why it shouldn't be secure, and that Server Core definitely does help in that effort. It's just the work of a proper configuration, and having a good strategy for testing / validating that everything is secured. It's not impossible or even impractical (look at Azure), just something that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2012 R2, PowerShell remoting is enabled by default